# Cron from php script not work

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, cron

I've added cron job to */etc/crontab* file in php script by method *file_put_contents* but this cron not execute. If I save this file in *nano* editor cron is work. Can to promtp why the cron that was added by php script not executed?
I tried reloaded cron daemon but this didn't help.
I use class for cron from article http://www.kavoir.com/2011/10/php-crontab-class-to-add-and-remove-cron-jobs.html.

I was changed method *saveJobs* for save crons to file */etc/crontab*.

```
static public function saveJobs($jobs = array()) {
    $output = file_put_contents('/etc/crontab', self::arrayToString($jobs));
    return $output;
}
```

Command for add cron

```
Crontab::addJob("*/1 * * * * root php -f /var/www/get_all_clients_data_db.php ");
```

Record for cron is added to crontab but this cron not execute.

*/etc/crontab*

```
# /etc/crontab: system-wide crontab
# Unlike any other crontab you don't have to run the `crontab'
# command to install the new version when you edit this file
# and files in /etc/cron.d. These files also have username fields,
# that none of the other crontabs do.

SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

# m h dom mon dow user  command
17 *    * * *   root    cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly
25 6    * * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily )
47 6    * * 7   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.weekly )
52 6    1 * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.monthly )
#
*/1 * * * * root php -f /var/www/get_all_clients_data_db.php
```

I apologize for mistakes. It's my first question on StackOverflow.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show your results. What you get after your script worked. Also show `ls -la /etc/crontab` after that.

Comment: Please share your code. No one can guess what you're trying to do.

Comment: fil_put_contents must be file_put_contents

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error. System logs `/var/log/syslog` had record

```
/usr/sbin/cron[8391]: (*system*) ERROR (Missing newline before EOF, this crontab file will be ignored)
```

when cron was added by script. After I added new line (\n) to method for adding cron it executed.

Answer (score 0):

Share your code, most probably you are missing linking shared library error. Just enable the crontab logging and check the exact error coming.

There is a command line option for logging. The output is saved to screenlog.n file, where n is a number of the screen. From man pages of screen:

‘-L’ Tell screen to turn on automatic output logging.

Start your program from screen and check the log why it is not running.

```
/usr/bin/screen -d -m -S -L CRMService /home/CRMService
```

Let me know if you stuck further!

Comment: When I add this cron in nano it's work. I've tried to run script in console. The script executed without errors. But if cron was added from script it doesn't started.

Comment: If open and save file crontab in nano after the cron was added from script the cron start execute.